# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: .so library is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a C library that I am hoping to wrap in JNI and call from my android project. The .so file is the following architecture: i386:x86-64. Whenever I add it to my project inside the src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a|armeabi-v7a|x86 folders, I get an error saying the .so file is 64-bit instead of 32-bit. I have tried cross-referencing this issue and noticed that people usually get the opposite issue, where the .so was 32-bit instead of 64-bit. I've tried combing through Android documentation to see where I messed up but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: The solution is to either use a 64-bit JVM or a 32-bit version of the C library. They have to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 64-bit library should not be in **src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a** folder. If your device supports **arm64-v8a** ABI, the app will be using the 64-bit library. If the device is not compatible, you cannot use this library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027837/force-app-to-run-32-bit-architecture-for-64-bit-devices?noredirect=1#comment104301237_59027837

Comment: will you pls check on this question?