# How to force AAB to install only in 32 bits

Tags: google-play, apk, 32bit-64bit, android-app-bundle

We have lost our project source long ago, we now need to force android app bundle to install 32-bit lib into 64b arch devices. At the same time we need to put dummy libs into arm64-v8a for google play to accept our app. Is there anyway we can force this install?

We cant edit gradle (lost srcs)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027837/force-app-to-run-32-bit-architecture-for-64-bit-devices

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately NO you can not do this, you have to have the source code.

Comment: How would i do that with source code.